# Варган и варганить

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Думаю, все знают, что варган — это древний музыкальный инструмент, распространенный у славян и народов Севера, состоящий из проволоки и издающий весьма характерные звуки.
При этом же мы знаем слово "варганить" или, точнее даже, "сварганить" — этакий пренебрежительно-насмешливый вариант слова "сделать": "А не сварганить ли нам каши на ужин?".
Я пытаюсь понять, какая связь между этими словами может быть? Слово "варган", как говорит Википедия, происходит от славянского "варга" — "рот".
Но при чем тут в таком случае "сделать"?

Answer (score 4):

Любопытное словцо. Варга на древнеславянских языках, действительно,  рот. А варган - древний музыкальный инструмент, имеющий более 200 названий. В Сицилии его называют челюстной арфой. По-тюркски - комус, комуз или хомус. Игра на варгане шумная, действует на мозги, поэтому варган считается шаманским медитативным инструментом. Только вот инструмент-то щипковый, при чём здесь уста? Может, в него ещё и дули? Вряд ли. Получается, что основное значение СВАРГАНИТЬ - быстро сварить или что-то изготовить - не от слова ВАРГАН, а от слова ВАРГА.

Есть в Интернете даже попытка объяснить древнерусское "варга" - уста, в котором выделяются две составных части "вар" и "га". Первое слово "вар" имеет много значений. Современные лингвисты и  предлагают массу значений (при желании легко можно найти в интернете). Одно из них связано с приготовлением пищи на огне.  Не случайно в первоначальном варианте "варганить" относилось к приготовлению пищи (сходство с "варить").
Вторая часть слова - "га" - указывает на аспект движения. Она происходит из индо-европейских языков. Можно встретить в названиях северных рек (Онега, Молога, Чурьега). Индо-европейские корни можно найти в санскрите: "йога" - путь к себе, "варга" - гармония, сила. Соответственно, можно предположить, что "вар"+"га" - путь пищи (массы), то есть уста, рот. Возможно, так и есть.

Но ВАРГАН на значение слова всё же повлиял.

У Фасмера: варгАн - ближайшая этимология: "примитивный муз. инструмент", др.-русск. оръганъ, укр. вiргаґни мн. (из *ворганъ), польск. organy, чеш. varhany "орган". Заимств. через польск. из лат. organum (возм., через бав. o§rgana) от греч. Фrganon.

Получается, что "варган" - видоизменение слова "орган". Итак, "сварганить" и "оргАн", на котором исполняют Баха, - одного корня. Причуды языка! Варганом родители могли прозвать шумливого младенца. Музыка органа - сильная, громкая, не все её воспринимают как мелодичную, связана с религией - очень близкие ассоциации с музыкой варгана - музыкой шаманов и скоморохов.

---

Словарь "Русские фамилии. Популярный этимологический словарь" объясняет фамилию Варганов. "Варга́н - старинный музыкальный инструмент, на котором играли скоморохи. Видимо, звучал он не очень усладительно; поэтому глагол "варганить" стал означать: плохо играть на чем-либо, шуметь, оглушать, а затем и что-либо наскоро, небрежно делать.

---

У Даля находим: Варганить - костромской диалект - " шуметь чем, стучать; работать что-либо со стуком". || Ряз. кур. вор. - делать что кой-как. || вологодск. -кипеть, закипать. Самовар варганит. Самовар заварганил. Сосед заварганил, начал стучать, работать. Что ты тут наварганил? наделал, настряпал. Подварганивать кому, подыгрывать, поддакивать. Все проварганил, промотал, прокутил. Разварганился, расшумелся, расказакался. Кой-как сварганили свадьбу, сладили. Варгасить пск. (варганить? врать?) болтать вздор, наговаривать, сплетничать.

Так что диалекты используют оба исходных слова - и варган (шуметь, делать абы как, на смех), и варга - (варить, стряпать, мастерить быстро из чего попало).

Омонимы слились в одно слово, и так бывает в языке.

Answer (score 4):

ВАРГАН

Варга́н (этимология неясна: либо от орган (ср. чеш. varhan), либо от древнеславянского варга — рот, уста, русское название язычкового народного инструмента. Относится к самозвучащим язычковым музыкальным инструментам. На варгане возможно извлечь только звуки натурального звукоряда.

Ещё в XIX в. музыковед Владимир Одоевский писал: «Нигде может быть нельзя собрать большего числа опытов по этому предмету, чем в России, где варганы составляют забаву почти всякого простолюдина». В стихотворении Н. А. Некрасова «В дороге» также упоминается варган: «На варгане играть и читать...»

КАК ИГРАЮТ НА ВАРГАНЕ

http://vargshop.ru/vse-o-vargane/samouchitel-igry-na-vargane/

Варган  - самозвучащий язычковый музыкальный инструмент. Представляет собой пластинку из дерева, кости, металла с язычком посередине. При игре варган прижимают к зубам или зажимают ими. Язычок варгана приводят в движение, крепко удерживая инструмент в одной руке, и ударяя по язычку пальцем второй руки. Удары должны быть не сильными, но резкими, непродолжительными и отрывистыми. 
Варган с одним язычком может звучать лишь на одной ноте, эта нота называется основным тоном варгана. Изменяется только тембр (оттенок) звука, который зависит от объёма и формы нашего естественного резонатора — ротовой полости, положения языка в ней и от положения глотки. В различных ситуациях в сложном звуке выделяются и усиливаются те или иные обертоны.

ВАРГАН И ВАРГАНИТЬ

Варганы предоставляют широкие возможности для импровизационной игры. Исполнителю не надо иметь музыкального образования, да и технику можно освоить за считанные дни. А дальше всё зависит  от чувства внутренней гармонии. На одной единственной ноте, умело используя обертоны, можно наиграть практически любое музыкальное произведение, а можно издавать  шум, только отдаленно  похожий на музыку.

Слово варганить появилось в русском языке с конца 18 века и сначала имело значение « играть в варган или неискусно играть на любом музыкальном инструменте».  Делать что-то наспех, быстро, шумно – вторичное значение слова, и оно связано с особенностями игры на варгане.

Answer (score 0):

*...как говорит Википедия, происходит от славянского "варга" — "рот".*
Так вот, у некоторых народов Севера (коми, эвенки, якуты, чукчи) делали пельмени. А фарш получали путём пережевывания мяса. Отсюда и слово "варганить".
Варган, соответственно, поэтому так же назван. Синоним музыкального инструмента — хомус.